# Cut out letters using bash

Tags: bash

I want to cut out extra words without losing the ranges that follow
emxaple :

```
int.domain.com<BR>stage.domain.com<BR>helth.domain.com
```

I want to remove it `<BR>`

Without losing it The two domains that follow 
`stage.domain.com`
`helth.domain.com`

I want to do that by using the grep tool

And thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/836748

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed

```
sed 's#<BR>#\n#g'
```

Demo:

```
:=>echo "int.domain.com<BR>stage.domain.com<BR>helth.domain.com"  | sed 's#<BR>#\n#g' 
int.domain.com
stage.domain.com
helth.domain.com
:=>
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, partially but still. Sed will not always substitute with `'\n'` - in cygwin/mingw for example, and more importantly how are you going to remove first domain from output as this was in a question?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `grep` alone to do that. `Grep` only searches patterns not substitutes them.

```
$ echo "int.domain.com<BR>stage.domain.com<BR>helth.domain.com" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="<BR>"} { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i }'
```

```
stage.domain.com
helth.domain.com
```

FS is field separator, then print all from 2'nd element.

Comment: Or just …`awk 1 RS='<BR>|\n'`, RS is the record separator, so tell awk you have records separated by `<BR>` or newlines

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Don't know where exactly is a catch here. It's not going to work as you wrote it - whole script must be in between `' '`.

Comment: mmm, I assumed GNU's awk, which handles regex record separators fine, I'd tested before commenting.